# Get ServletContext in EnvironmentPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly

I'm trying to get ServletContext in the class which is implementing EnvironmentPostProcessor. ServletContext is required to get the war filename. Based on war file name I get properties from a database and will set to properties to user later in the applications.

I'm not using Embedded Container but WildFly Server

```
public class ClEnvironment implements EnvironmentPostProcessor, ServletContextAware, ServletContextInitializer
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t get the `ServletContext` in an `EnvironmentPostProcessor`. The post-processors are loaded from `spring.factories` very early in the application’s lifecycle. With an embedded servlet container that happens long before the container has been started and the `ServletContext` is available.

This may be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Perhaps you could ask another question that explains what you are trying to do. There may be another way to do it that does not require access to the `ServletContext` in an environment post-processor.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've updated my question. Basically I need to get the war file name using ServletContext. Based on name I get application properties from a database and will set to properties to use later in the application